# Center absolute position div in windowed mode?

Tags: html, center, absolute, windowed

I centered this absolute div:

```
<div style="
width:800px;
height:190px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-400px;
border-width:10px;
border-style:solid;">
</div>
```

In maximized mode, it works normally. But when the width of the browser is smaller the div, I can't scroll to the left of the div, it was cut. I tested on Chrome and IE9

How can I center absolute div in windowed mode? What is the reason it is out of alignment?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to change the `div`'s width and height to percent values and then to center it, just do something like this:

```
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
```

Comment: When the width of the browser is smaller than the div, there is a scroll bar in the bottom. But I can't scroll to the left of the div, it was cut, I don't know why

Comment: That's because your `div` is set to `position:absolute;` which sets its vertical position above everything else, including `<html>`. This means that the `div` does not stretch the `html` element, so the browser doesn't know it needs to scroll left.

Comment: Maybe what you need is to set the width of the `div` to something like `width:70%;` instead of `width:800px;`, so that it'll change its width according to the window.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to keep static width:800px because I want to align with other element? Or anyway to tell browser scrolling to the left using javascript/jquery?

Comment: Well, if you want the `div` to have dynamic width, you'll need to use percent values. The centering will work regardless if you use px or % widths, but if your window is smaller than the size of the `div`, it'll be cut off. Also, not sure about the JS. Don't think it'll work.